# Numerical Value That Appears Several Times in Same Column

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have a table, Employees. I want to display the same month when employees were hired in department 50, 60, and 80. This is the code I wrote:

```
    select to_char(hire_date, 'Month') as "Month Name" 
    from employees
    where department_id = any (50, 60, 80);
```

However, this displays all the months when employees were hired in the three departments:

```
    Month Name
    January
    May
    February
    November
    October
    January
    March
    July
    January
    May
    March
```

Since January is the same month that appears in all three departments, I only want January to be displayed. How should I fix that?

Comment: You're looking for a month (ignoring year?) in which people in all three departments were hired? Sample data and results would be helpful. With the standard HR-schema employees table only February matches if you're looking at month and year; January, February and May match if you ignore the year. If I've understood at all...

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you made the explanation clearer in the question, and also fixed the title - why does it refer to different columns? - and tags.

Comment: Yes, I'm just looking for a single month, it's for a trivia thing, "In which month did Department 50, 60, and 80 all hire employees?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count how many departments actually matched, which means you need to group by the month; and then filter on those that have the same number of matches as the number of departments you were looking for:

```
select to_char(hire_date, 'Month') as "Month Name" 
from employees
where department_id = any (50, 60, 80)
group by to_char(hire_date, 'Month')
having count(distinct department_id) = 3;

Month Name                          
------------------------------------
January  
February 
May
```

That is looking for the same month in any year - which I guess might be useful to see who has anniversaries coming up. If you really want the same actual month, in the same year, then the grouping needs to include the year:

```
select to_char(trunc(hire_date, 'MM'), 'Month') as "Month Name" 
from employees
where department_id = any (50, 60, 80)
group by trunc(hire_date, 'MM')
having count(distinct department_id) = 3;

Month Name                          
------------------------------------
February
```

This is with the standard HR schema's employee table; you may have different data in yours if you've been modifying it. In this data there are 12 people who are in one of those departments with a hire date in any February; three were hired in February 1999, one in each of those departments.